# 'IV2SLS' object has no attribute 'pinv_wexog'

Tags: python, statsmodels

I import IV2SLS from statsmodels.sandbox.regression.gmm,

but it failed to do heteroscedasticity robust covariance.

```
from statsmodels.sandbox.regression.gmm import IV2SLS

endog = cig_1995['lpackpc']
exog = cig_1995[['constant', 'lravgprs']]
instrument = cig_1995[['constant', 'rtaxso']]
results = IV2SLS(endog=endog,exog=exog,instrument=instrument).fit()
results = results.get_robustcov_results(cov_type='HC1')

AttributeError: 'IV2SLS' object has no attribute 'pinv_wexog'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `linearmodels` package which contains a working and tested implementation of [`IV2SLS`](https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/iv/iv/linearmodels.iv.model.IV2SLS.html). The syntax is nearly the same as that incomplete version in `statsmodels`. The only difference is how you specify the covariance estimator, which is part of [`fit`](https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/iv/iv/linearmodels.iv.model.IV2SLS.fit.html).

```py
from linearmodels import IV2SLS

endog = cig_1995['lpackpc']
exog = cig_1995[['constant', 'lravgprs']]
instrument = cig_1995[['constant', 'rtaxso']]
results = IV2SLS(endog=endog,exog=exog,instrument=instrument).fit(cov_type="robust")
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is difficult to do F test for full/reduced model using linearmodels.

Comment: The results instance has a `wald_test` function that lets you test restrictions.  Perhaps not as simple as literally testing two results instances.